# How Run a notebook that uses csv files in amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, deep-learning

For a personal project, I have to use EC2 for a jupyter notebook. However, this notebook uses csv files from my computer. So, my question is how do you upload your csv files in the AWS server??

For the moment, I can run the notebook with the EC2 server, but that's all.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that in AWS.

For example:

- You can ssh or rdp to your EC2 server (depending on what connection protocol it is), then scp or simply copy your CSV files to the EC2 server. This is one of the most straightforward ways. Depending on what storage is available for your EC2 server, you might store it in the instance storage, an EFS, an EBS etc. But instance storage is only temporary. If you terminate the instance, the CSV files will be gone for example.
- You can manually upload your CSV files to your S3 bucket, grant your EC2 permission to access the S3 bucket where it stores the CSV files
- Mount the AWS EFS on your on-prem storage, and transfer the CSV files to the AWS EFS, which connects to the EC2 instance
- Upload your CSV to a git repo, ssh into your EC2, and git clone your CSV to the EC2 instance
- Use AWS Direct Connect to establish a network connection to your computer to access the CSV

The list goes on and among these options, there are many configurations that needed to be done, for example, setting up the IAM role, configuring the security group and NAT if you use them, etc.

Fastest way to do it, since you mention how do you upload the csv files in the AWS server, is just to ssh or rdp into your AWS EC2 instance depending on the connection protocol and copy the csv files to your EC2 instance.